# BeautifulSoup return next sibling after using findAll(text=' ')

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

How would I go about getting the next sibling using bs4 after I've located the contents that I want by searching the HTML using soup.findAll

```
<td class="name">David<span class="flag away"</span>
</td>
    <td class="team">b<span class="team b"></span></td>
    <td class="time">99'</td>

<td class="name">James<span class="flag home"</span>
</td>
    <td class="team">a<span class="team a"></span></td>
    <td class="time">99'</td>
```

using find all I can locate the text

```
for t in soup.findAll(text='David'):
>> David
```

However my desired outupt is

```
<td class="team">b<span class="team b"></span></td>
<td class="time">99'</td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup, Tag


input = """<td class="name">David<span class="flag away"</span>
</td>
    <td class="team">b<span class="team b"></span></td>
    <td class="time">99'</td>

<td class="name">James<span class="flag home"</span>"""

web_soup = soup(input)
for t in web_soup.findAll(text='David'):
    for item in t.parent.next_siblings:
        if isinstance(item, Tag):
            if 'class' in item.attrs and 'name' in item.attrs['class']:
                break
            print item
```

prints:

```
<td class="team">b<span class="team b"></span></td>
<td class="time">99'</td>
```

Hope that is what you wanted.